# Inconsistencies while pushing git lfs files

Tags: git, git-lfs

I am trying to push my commits in a git repo so that I can access my saved model in kaggle and take the weights without training again. The problem is I am getting error messages again and again and it's wildly inconsistent.

```
Prakhar@PrakharPC MINGW64 ~/Documents/Misc/College/RSM/MVQA-RSM (main)
$ git push -u origin main
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/PrakharArya-Rex/MVQA-RSM/': OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to github.com:443
```

or sometimes it initiates but doesn't start pushing

```
Prakhar@PrakharPC MINGW64 ~/Documents/Misc/College/RSM/MVQA-RSM (main)
$ git push -u origin main
Uploading LFS objects:  82% (9/11), 229 MB | 0 B/s, done.
batch response: Post "https://github.com/PrakharArya-Rex/MVQA-RSM.git/info/lfs/objects/batch": EOF
batch response: Post "https://github.com/PrakharArya-Rex/MVQA-RSM.git/info/lfs/objects/batch": EOF
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/PrakharArya-Rex/MVQA-RSM'
```

And sometimes it starts pushing and stops midway

```
Prakhar@PrakharPC MINGW64 ~/Documents/Misc/College/RSM/MVQA-RSM (main)
$ git push -u origin main
Uploading LFS objects:  82% (9/11), 345 MB | 1.8 MB/s, done.
batch response: Post "https://github.com/PrakharArya-Rex/MVQA-RSM.git/info/lfs/objects/batch": EOF
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/PrakharArya-Rex/MVQA-RSM'
```

Though as you can see some refs were pushed orginally and this happened in the same way. I got these inconsistent errors but somehow some got pushed. Any way to resolve it or should I brute force until the refs are uploaded.